# Is quantum entanglement an example of consciousness at the quantum level?

Tags: consciousness, quantum-interpretations, panpsychism, monism, hardproblem

This is a philosophical question about the relation between quantum physics and consciousness. Is Bell's Theorem related to free will and consciousness at the quantum level? If consciousness is universal, is the hard problem of consciousness really a problem? Are matter and consciousness inextricably entwined? Is the universe made of matter-consciousness? See Goff, Seager, Springer, et al.

---

With respect to the question, I rephrase it.

*Since it seems that quantum physics is leading us towards a non-local universe which is non-deterministic and non-predictable could it be that somehow this new structure (view of the world) that emerges may have consciousness as the connecting glue?*

Comment: Two close votes after seven views within the hour? Perhaps someone should look into that?

Comment: It's not clear what consciousness would be doing as the glue. Any functional aspect of nature would need to have consciousness as an additional assumption. So whatever is the "gluing property" need not imply an associated subjectiity.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to answer my own question before certain people close it. My answer is that I do not know. It is worthy of consideration. As a scientist and a philosopher, my hypothesis is that consciousness is involved in the fundamental nature of matter. Any ideas on an experiment to test this would be welcomed.

Comment: Sounds like Stuart Hameroff's Orch OR research.  Experiments inconclusive but did not disprove Orch OR.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. This seems to deal with quantum events within neurons.  My question does not deal with human consciousness specifically. The hypothesis is that consciousness exists at the quantum level.

Comment: As an anaesthesiologist Hameroff heard reports from patients of out-of-body experiences where they saw things from perspectives that they shouldn't have been able to see.  He theorised the mind was de-localising from the brain under the influence of the anaesthetic. I.e. "innumerable subjects have reported conscious awareness seemingly separating from the subject’s brain and physical body" – [The "Quantum Soul"](https://galileocommission.org/the-quantum-soul-a-scientific-hypothesis-hameroff-chopra-2012/)